# Copying JS events from one element to another

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I'm attempting to copy events from one element, to another using pure JS (i.e. not JQuery).

The bug I'm hitting, is when there's multiple events, the last event is used for both.

Bit hard to explain, please refer to my [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/vomikapa/2/edit), I want to copy the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events from `#foo` to `#bar`. The bug is, the mouseup event is fired for both `mouseup` and `mousedown` on the `#bar` element.

Here's the code snippet I'm currently working with, to copy events.

```
copyEvents(fromEl, toEl, ['onmousedown', 'onmouseup']);

function copyEvents(fromEl, toEl, events){
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    var event = events[i];
    var func = fromEl[events[i]];
    if(func){
      if (console){ console.log('Copying event - ' + event + ' = ' + func); }
      toEl[event] = function(evt){ func.call(this); };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Assign the function directly `toEl[event] = func`. http://jsbin.com/wowap/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSHint warning on your example should give you a tip on what's happening:

> Don't make functions within a loop

The root of your problem is [the JavaScript infamous loop issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue).

If you loop with `forEach` you avoid this issue altogether as you introduce a new scope:

```
function copyEvents(fromEl, toEl, events){
  events.forEach(function(ev, i) {
    var func = fromEl[ev];
    if(func){
      toEl[ev] = function(evt){ func.call(this); };
    }
  });
}
```

But you don't need an anonymous function. You can keep your current code if you simply assign the function directly:

```
toEl[event] = func;
```

That will work because `this` is dynamic, resolved when the function is called.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/wowap/1/edit

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I can't believe I walked right past `toEl[event] = func;`.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy over the function(s) you also give the element which you copied the functions to the same `this` object as the element you copy from. So it triggers on both of them.

You need to assign them individually instead of copying the functionality.